# Could not resolve io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt:detekt-gradle-plugin

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin, bintray, jcenter

Suddenly from the today morning we start facing the issue in our build process with following dependency error.

[image]

we are using `id("io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt").version("1.5.1")` plugin in our gradle and repositories mentioned as follows.

```
repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }
```

I've checked the gradle status https://status.gradle.com/ but there are no outage reported.

Comment: is [this](https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/gitlab/arturbosch/detekt/detekt-gradle-plugin/1.5.1/detekt-gradle-plugin-1.5.1.module) accessible with normal browser for you ? its not for me, not even other versions, so i dont expect you can build unless you do some changes.

Comment: It is still not accessible, but currently its working fine. I'm not sure that the issue was from Gradle or Jcenter.

Comment: I found another one asking about a solution for `jcecnter` shutdown, so i guess it was `jcenter` related issue.

Answer (score 0):

Jcenter() is down, You can't access any more.

was available in read-only mode after sunset , you can check `http://status.bintray.com/`

Comment: The issue is currently resolved. I guess it was not relevant to bintray.com as http://status.bintray.com/ is still not accessible to me but build is working fine.
I've just rechecked the https://status.gradle.com/uptime, where I can see today one incident they have reported. So might be that was the cause